# PowerPivot remove subtotals by default

Tags: excel, powerpivot, subtotal

Is there a way eliminate subtotals by default in PowerPivot?

If fields are selected, it is possible to manually remove the subtotals from the worksheet. However, after removing and then re-adding the fields I see subtotals again.

If possible, how can I default to this behavior in which no subtotals are shown by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something defined in the Power Pivot semantic model, but a default behavior of pivot tables in Excel.

[I'm sure you're familiar with the ribbon menu option to disable all subtotals in a pivot table.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-subtotals-and-totals-in-a-PivotTable-fc4d8406-f230-4762-aa2f-310826f3e5e2) I am unsure if there is a way to change Excel's default behavior.